# how display button for special users django

Tags: python, django

How can display button example ' `download file.pdf` ' for special users in django.

- Django version 2, 1, 0
- Python version 3.7.0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The more clearly you ask your question, the more likely you'll get a helpful answer. [ask] has some great tips for doing this well. What do you mean by "special users"?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the template to show a button, in this case just for the superusers:

```
{% if request.user.is_superuser %}
  <a href="path/to/file/to/download" download>
    <img src="buttonimage.jpg" >
  </a>
{% else %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

If you want to show this to specific user names or to user groups you need to adapt change the if clause.

Comment: (a) There can be more than one superuser. (b) OP didn't specify what they mean by "special users". What makes you think they're asking about superusers?

Comment: this is just an example for the logic behind. He did not ask how to distinguish users/groups etc. However, I editted the answer.

Comment: how i make specific user names in admin ?

Comment: django auth should be preinstalled in the admin. Just create new users in the database table user.